# GAE prefers webapp2 or flask?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

So if you go through [cloud.google.com](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction), it runs you through using webapp2.

But if you go through the [console](https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine), it asks you to use Flask, Django, or Bottle, with no mention of webapp2.

What's current best practice?

Comment: All the web frameworks you list are fine and well supported in GAE.  Django's very rich and thus inevitably heavyweight -- does a lot for you but maybe not the way you'd prefer.  webapp2 is at the opposite extreme, very lightweight.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941145/python-flask-vs-bottle for flask-bottle comparisons (from back before StackOverflow condemned "too opinion based" questions, which this one will no doubt be closed as).

Answer (score 1):

Converting comment to answer...

All the web frameworks you list are fine and well supported in GAE. Django's very rich and thus inevitably heavyweight -- does a lot for you but maybe not the way you'd prefer. webapp2 is at the opposite extreme, very lightweight. See [stackoverflow.com/questions/4941145/python-flask-vs-bottle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941145/python-flask-vs-bottle) for flask-bottle comparisons (from back before StackOverflow condemned "too opinion based" questions, which this one will no doubt be closed as). – Alex Martelli